# Down arrow icon in Select Tag

Tags: html, html-select

Hi I would like to know how I put to the following code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Torrecilla/Yv6zx/3/

This arrow to the right: [image: select arrow]

Is it possible? I could not figure it out

```
<select name="cats" id="cats">
  <option value="">All the Categories</option>
  <option value="">Cat 1</option>
  <option value="">Cat 2</option>
  <option value="">...</option>
</select>​
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
}
select {
    padding:3px;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 
        0 0px 0 #ccc,
        0 0px #fff inset;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FBFBFB 0%, #E9E9E9 100%);background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#FBFBFB), color-stop(100%,#E9E9E9));
    color:black;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-appearance:none; 
    cursor:pointer;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible! Try this:

CSS:

```
background: url('http://i45.tinypic.com/309nb74.png') no-repeat right, -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FBFBFB 0%, #E9E9E9 100%);
background: url('http://i45.tinypic.com/309nb74.png') no-repeat right, -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#FBFBFB), color-stop(100%,#E9E9E9));
```

You will need to adjust the padding, but you get the idea.

DEMO:

http://jsfiddle.net/Yv6zx/24/